# Java output file doesnt recognise \n as linebreak

Tags: java

for a Java project for a University Class I have a method that saves ASCII images as a uniline string and another method called toString rebuilds this ASCII image and returns as a string. When I run my program on the Eclipse my output looks on console alright and multiline, and there are line breaks where they should be. But when I run it with the command line with a redirected outputfile

java myprogram < input > output

the text in the output is uniline without line breaks

Here is the code of the method

```
public String toString(){

    String output = "";

    for(int i=0; i<height; i++){
        output=output+image.substring(i*width, i*width+width)+"\n";

        }
    return output;  
}
```

What should I do so I can get a multiline output text file

Comment: What text editor are you using? This will vary, if you're on Windows, try viewing it in Notepad++

Comment: would it have been different If I have checked it by mac texteditor?

Comment: As Chris Thompson said, the reason being that on Windows the line end is formed by `\r\n`, and the normal NotePad for instance obstinately refuses to recognize Linux/Unix line end `\n`. BTW better use a StringBuilder for better memory usage; considerably faster!

Comment: can I use String builder for varying number of lines? Because the height(number of the lines) will change depending on th input image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A faster solution with \r\n when Windows:

```
public String toString() {
    final String EOL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    final int EOL_LENGTH = EOL.length();
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder(image.length() + EOL_LENGTH * height);
    output.append(image);
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        output.insert(i*(width + EOL_LENGTH) + width, EOL);
    }
    return output.toString();  
}
```

Comment: wouldn't you just `append()`?

Comment: @Bohemian: yes, but taking `height` times a substring should not be too much faster than an insert. Just showing the StringBuilder API.

Answer (score 3):

It may be the case that `\n` isn't the correct line separator for the operating system you are running. With Java, it's best to use `System.getProperty("line.separator");` for creating newline characters, as [this will ensure you are using the correct one for the platform](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html).